# Setting asset_host from within a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For whatever reason, I cannot get the full path to my asset URLs with `asset_url` when calling a view that uses `asset_url` from within a worker. If I render the view from the controller, then `asset_url` shows the full URL including `http://`

Here's what I'm loading in my worker:

```
        av = ActionView::Base.new()
        av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths

        # need these in case your view constructs any links or references any helper methods.
        av.class_eval do
          include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
          include ApplicationHelper
        end

        cover_html = av.render(:template => "reports/cover_page.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8",
```

When it gets to `cover_page.html.erb`, the `asset_url` called from within it doesn't load `http://server/path/to/image.png` like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need view helpers in a worker. Seems not right to me (maybe there is a different way of achieving what you are doing or maybe your business requirement is unique)

Answering to your question, `asset_url` is part or `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper`, so try including it,

```rb
av.class_eval do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the WickedPDF gem and there's no other way (that I know of) to generate the PDF without generating the HTML first, which comes from the view. Unfortunately this didn't seem to do anything different for me. `asset_url` still gets displayed as a relative path. Is it because it's not loading the default `asset_host` to prepend automatically to `asset_url`? Guessing that usually loads with the rails app, but not with workers, etc.?